# Why isn't the information inside of my DB printing?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

So I'm running a test program trying to figure out sqlite here, I'm just trying to print the information inside of my DB after I INSERT it from an object, why isn't fetchall printing any information in the DB?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

cursor = conn.cursor()



class User:
    def __init__(self, category, email, username, password):
        self.category = category
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.__version = 1

    def __str__(self):
            return f"""
        Category: {self.category}
        Email: {self.email}
        Username: {self.username}
        Password: {self.password}
        """

def spinUpDB():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE test (
                    category text PRIMARY KEY,
                    email text,
                    username text,
                    password text)""")
    conn.commit()


spinUpDB()

category = input("Enter category: ")
email = input("Enter email: ")
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter pass: ")


user1 = User(category, email, username, password)

conn.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (:category, :email, :username, :password)",
             {'category': user1.category, 'email': user1.email, 'username': user1.username, 'password': user1.password})
print(user1)
conn.commit()

conn.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE category=:category", {'category':'yt'})
conn.commit()
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run `.execute()` on `cursor` instead of `conn`

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE category=:category", {'category':'t1'})
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

also note there's no need in `.commit()` after `SELECT` statement.

When you run `conn.execute` instead `cursor.execute`, it returns you a new instance of cursor and your initial `cursor` in the next line is not running a select query

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall):

> **execute(sql[, parameters])**
> This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates a cursor object by calling the cursor() method, calls the cursor’s execute() method with the parameters given, and returns the cursor.

Comment: haha.. I need some sleep. Thanks a lot, can't believe I missed that.